# How to write a file in python?

Tags: python

i am having trouble figuring out how to get this code to write a file. i am using python 3.8

```
text = open("readfilein6.txt", "r") 


d = dict() 

for line in text:      
    line = line.strip() 

    line = line.lower() 
 
    words = line.split(" ") 

    for word in words: 
   
        if word in d: 
        
            d[word] = d[word] + 1
        else: 
        
            d[word] = 1

for key in list(d.keys()): 
    print(key, d[key])
```

this is my failed attempt at writing a file

```
file1= ("outputini6.txt")
with open(file1, "w") as file_object:
    file_object.write(key, d[key])
```

i get this error message:

```
file_object.write(key, d[key])
TypeError: write() takes exactly one argument (2 given)
```

it prints exactly what i need, but i also need it to write a file

Comment: try `file.write(string)`

Comment: Please always add your complete error message, if you have one, to your question or, if your code isn't doing what you expect, post your expected and actual results. You say that your attempt to write fails, but you don't describe how it's failed. Also, use the Python tag for most questions. 585 people watch for questions with the Python-3.8 tag, vs 1.3m for Python

Comment: The error message is telling you exactly what the problem is.  Your line of code `file_object.write(key, d[key])` is wrong because the `write` method takes a single parameter, not two. You could write `key` and `d[key]` with two calls to`write`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You actually was really close:

```
text = open("readfilein6.txt", "r")

d = dict()

for line in text:
    line = line.strip()

    line = line.lower()

    words = line.split(" ")

    for word in words:

        if word in d:

            d[word] = d[word] + 1
        else:

            d[word] = 1
file1 = "outputini6.txt"
with open(file1, "w") as file_object:
    for key in list(d.keys()):
        print(key, d[key])
        file_object.write(f"{key} {d[key]}\n")
```

The things i changed are the write, so to enter both key and value. i also called the write before the loop to not overide the saved data and write all at the same time.

Comment: That really helped, Thank you!

Comment: Its what you intend to? need more help?